# log4j- using specific logger but showing the class name

Tags: java, log4j

Until now, I've used a method with log4j like this:

```
void writeMethod(String msg){
  StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
  Logger log=Logger.getLogger(st[2]);
  log.info(msg);
}
```

This, together with the properties, allowed me to show in the log file the class/method which called the write method and it worked fine, for as long as I only needed one log file per application run. Now I have more threads per application and I need more than 1 log file per application (number can be, virtually, unlimited).
Since I wish to have more than 1 log files, I create the log4j.properties file at application start time automatically and then use a specific appender for each thread of the application.

So the appenders are named like `l0, l1, l2 ....` and each one writes to a different log file.

This means that I am now using something like:

```
void writeMethod(int threadNr ,String msg){

      Logger log=Logger.getLogger("l"+threadNr);
      log.info(msg);
    }
```

**My question is: can I use this second method AND also have the previous functionality of being able to write the method/class which called the logging method?**

Comment: Any particular reason for doing it this way? Log4j can be configured to output the class, method and thread name.

Comment: can you provide such an example? Because the second version just writes l0, l1 when I tell it to output the class.

Comment: Does my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a properties file to configure my log4j. Example of a layout...

```
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

And here's a link to a [log4j reference](http://www.daniel-hirscher.de/Java_files/Log4jQuickRef.pdf). If you want files for each thread you could always create multiple appenders and create logger for each one. Eg.

```
// In your log4j config
log4j.logger.1=DEBUG

// In you code
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("1.ClassName");
```

Comment: I used something similar, before seeing your answer, which also answers my question. Thank you